# Getting Y co-ordinate of a page in mpdf

Tags: pdf-generation, mpdf

I am using mpdf to generate certain tables on a pdf. Each table has a title text on top of it. I want to know the current y coordinate of the page to make the output proper. Currently sometimes the title comes on 1 page and the table on the next

```
I tried using $mpdf->GetY()
```

but it gives an error. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i got the solution to my question..used $mpdf->y which returned my y position. So i could check if the y position is greater than the approx height of the table. :)

Answer (score 0):

`class mPDF` has a public property `$y`

You can directly get Y co-ordinate by accessing this variable.

Check if that works for you.